# reverse an array and store it in a new field in all mongo documents of a collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have one array in mongo document. I need to reverse this array and add a new array(with reversed value) in the document. I need to do this for all the document in the mongo collections. How do I do it?
I am trying with below script but this is taking a lot of time so need a faster way to do it

```
db.collections.find().forEach(function (doc) {
    var loc = [ doc.sourceArray[1], doc.sourceArray[0] ]; 
    db.collections.update(doc, { $set: {destinationArray: loc } });
})
```

Comment: Maybe look into aggregation from MongoDB

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) to generate new field and [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) + [$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/index.html) to scan one array and create reversed one. Then you need [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) to redirect your aggregation results into a new collection. If you specify the same collection name, current collection will be overwritten

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            reversedArray: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$array",
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: {
                        $concatArrays: [ ["$$this"], "$$value" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $out: "collection"
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Kd0ZAJjkzCR)